# iOS drawRect not reading color property correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a subclass of UITableViewCell and i am trying to paint a line inside drawRect.

There is a property `separatorColor` in the header of sublass:

```
@interface DXDecisionsTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *separatorColor;
@end
```

And drawRect looks like this:

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGRect cellBounds = self.bounds;
    CGRect separatorRect = CGRectMake(0, cellBounds.size.height - kDXDecisionsTableViewCellSeparatorHeight, cellBounds.size.width, kDXDecisionsTableViewCellSeparatorHeight);

    NSAssert(self.separatorColor, @"separator color not set");
    NSLog(@"%@", [self.separatorColor stringValue]);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.separatorColor.CGColor);
    //[self.separatorColor setFill];
    //[[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
    //CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    //self.separatorColor = [UIColor redColor];
    //CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.separatorColor.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, separatorRect);

    //NSLog(@"self is %p", self);
}
```

If i set a color inside `drawRect` then it works and i have no idea why.

If i print a value of `separatorColor` i get `#c7c7cc`, even though in initializer it is `#7f00ffb2` which is correct.

Initializer:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code

    self.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5f green:0.0f blue:1.0f alpha:0.7f];
    NSLog(@"%@", [self.separatorColor stringValue]);
}
```

I am testing on the simulator.

Comment: please, show us the initializer

Comment: @Sulthan Added initializer.

Comment: As a side note as you supposed to set things on the drawing context without restoring them?

Comment: @Glorfindel Interesting. It is being called two times instead of once. Second time in a method `#1 0x007abdc0 in __53-[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]_block_invoke ()
`

Comment: Omg. I renamed the property to separatorColor1 and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your property name to `separatorColor2` - that should prevent Apple's own code to set your `separatorColor`.

Comment: I have just did that and it worked. I renamed it to separatorColor1. Regardless, i'll mark this as correct.